# Does she pronounce differently for these fiance's?

Tags: pronunciation

> [1 fiˈɒnseɪ  ; 2 fiˈɑːnseɪ](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fiance)

To my ear, it sounds like both pronunciations are the same. Does she (real woman or machine, I don’t know) pronounce (1) for both symbols, or pronounce (1) and (2) differently as the phonetic symbols denote? If they're different, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Are you asking about fiancé, or fiancée, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. fee-on-SAY
2. fee-ON-say

As AmE from So Cal, I pronounce like #2, with accent on second to last syllable.
Example
I would like to introduce to you my fee-ON-say.

Here is a Youtube audio.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUY61e5TcIU

Answer (score 3):

The vowels/ɒ/ and /ɑː/ are pronounced differently. The first  is slightly shorter than the second, and voice slightly farther back in the mouth, The speaker's lips are more rounded in the first.